# Angular, Is calling class methods by making 'instance' of that class and by using 'this' keyword is same?

Tags: angular

> demo.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent  {
    addBorderStyle : boolean = false;
    alterStyle(){
      console.log("Before Value:",this.addBorderStyle)
      this.addBorderStyle = !this.addBorderStyle
      console.log("After Value",this.addBorderStyle)
    }
    callByInstance(){
       let demoComp = new DemoComponent()
       demoComp.alterStyle()
    }
    callByThisKeyword(){
        this.alterStyle();
    }
}
```

> demo.component.html

```
<div   [ngClass]="addBorderStyle ? 'primary' : 'danger'" > <!-- If true adds primary class-->
        <p >I am test para</p>
</div>
<button (click)='callByThisKeyword()'>Call By this keyword</button> <!-- This does not changes ngClass--> 
<button (click)='callByInstance()'>Call By instance</button> <!-- This changes ngClass-->
```

upon running above code ,
Clicking on 1st button (Call By instance keyword)

```
  Output:
  Before Value:false
  After Value:true
```

Now class is altered and changes style through ngClass

Clicking on 2nd button (Call By this keyword)

```
  Output:
  Before Value:false
  After Value:true
```

Now class is not altered and does not changes style through ngClass **(styles are not applied)**,so why is that even though
console has logged altered values **ngClass** is not watching *( In some methods **'this'** does not refres to DemoComponent and sometimes arrow function is not an option so i use by making instance and calling methods but not working )* .How can i call method if **'this'** does not refers to **DemoComponent**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of your component that Angular created internally is bound to the `demo.component.html` that you have defined in the `@Component`. The instance that you are creating manually in your code `let demoComp = new DemoComponent()` though it contains the variables and all the properties of the component class, it is not bound to the template. Hence, any changes made in your `demoComp` instance will not be visible to you in the HTML.